# Magento 1.9.2 PayPal 3D Secure Setup Error - "this card has failed validation and cannot be used"

Tags: payment-methods, secure, paypal-payments-pro

I am experiencing difficulty in setting up 3D Secure Card Validation feature in Magento 1.9.2 in system/configuration/payment_methods and system/configuration/payment_systems.

The thread on this forum suggests that the issue/bug is not isolated to just myself and despite following the suggested fix on the forum I am unable to resolve the issue.

https://understandinge.com/forum/payment-gateways/magento-paypal-3d-secure-error-this-card-has-failed-validation-and-cannot-be-used/

ISSUE/BUG

I am getting the error message when I use PayPal Website Pro to process visa, mastercard or maestro card payments with 3D Secure (CardinalCommerce) Card Verification enabled in system/configuration/payment_methods - “this card has failed validation and cannot be used”

It's clear the moment 3D secure in Magento is enabled, the pop up message appears-  “this card has failed validation and cannot be used” when trying to use a Visa or MasterCard card n the checkout.

From reading similar issues experienced by others it appears it may be connected to the file lib/3Dsecure/CentinelClient.php

Can anyone assist please?

Below is the code contained within my CentinelClient.php file

```
   <?php
// Distributed by license from CardinalCommerce Corporation
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  CardinalCommerce (http://www.cardinalcommerce.com)
//  CentinelClient.php
//  Version 1.2 02/17/2005
//
//      Usage
//              The CentinelClient class is defined to assist integration efforts with the Centinel
//              XML message integration. The class implements helper methods to construct, send, and
//              receive XML messages with respect to the Centinel XML Message APIs.
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    require("XMLParser.php");
        include "CentinelErrors.php";

    class CentinelClient {

                var $request ;
                var $response ;
                var $parser;

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Function Add(name, value)
                //
                // Add name/value pairs to the Centinel request collection.
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                function add($name, $value) {
                         $this->request[$name] = $this->escapeXML($value);
                }

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Function getValue(name)
                //
                // Retrieve a specific value for the give name within the Centinel response collection.
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                function getValue($name) {
                    if (isset($this->response[$name])) {
                return $this->response[$name];
                    }else{
                        return "";
                    }
                }


                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Function getRequestXml(name)
                //
                // Serialize all elements of the request collection into a XML message, and format the required
                // form payload according to the Centinel XML Message APIs. The form payload is returned from
                // the function.
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                function getRequestXml(){
                        $queryString = "<CardinalMPI>";
                        foreach ($this->request as $name => $value) {
                                $queryString = $queryString."<".($name).">".($value)."</".($name).">" ;
                        }
                        $queryString = $queryString."</CardinalMPI>";
                        return "cmpi_msg=".urlencode($queryString);
                }

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Function sendHttp(url, "", $timeout)
                //
                // HTTP POST the form payload to the url using cURL.
                // form payload according to the Centinel XML Message APIs. The form payload is returned from
                // the function.
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                function sendHttp($url, $connectTimeout="", $timeout) {

                    // verify that the URL uses a supported protocol.

                        if( (strpos($url, "http://")=== 0) || (strpos($url, "https://")=== 0) ) {

                                //Construct the payload to POST to the url.

                                $data = $this->getRequestXml();
                                // create a new cURL resource

                                $ch = curl_init($url);

                                // set URL and other appropriate options
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  3);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

                                // Execute the request.

                                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                                $succeeded  = curl_errno($ch) == 0 ? true : false;

                                // close cURL resource, and free up system resources

                                curl_close($ch);

                                // If Communication was not successful set error result, otherwise

                                if(!$succeeded) {

                                        $result = $this->setErrorResponse(CENTINEL_ERROR_CODE_8030, CENTINEL_ERROR_CODE_8030_DESC);

                                }

                                // Assert that we received an expected Centinel Message in reponse.

                                if (strpos($result, "<CardinalMPI>") === false) {
                                        $result = $this->setErrorResponse(CENTINEL_ERROR_CODE_8010, CENTINEL_ERROR_CODE_8010_DESC);
                                }


                        } else {
                                $result = $this->setErrorResponse(CENTINEL_ERROR_CODE_8000, CENTINEL_ERROR_CODE_8000_DESC);
                        }
                        $parser = new XMLParser;
                        $parser->deserializeXml($result);
                        $this->response = $parser->deserializedResponse;
                }

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Function setErrorResponse(errorNo, errorDesc)
                //
                // Initialize an Error response to ensure that parsing will be handled properly.
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                function setErrorResponse($errorNo, $errorDesc) {

                  $resultText  = "<CardinalMPI>";
                  $resultText = $resultText."<ErrorNo>".($errorNo)."</ErrorNo>" ;
                  $resultText = $resultText."<ErrorDesc>".($errorDesc)."</ErrorDesc>" ;
                  $resultText  = $resultText."</CardinalMPI>";

                  return $resultText;
                }

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Function escapeXML(value)
                //
                // Escaped string converting all '&' to '&amp;' and all '<' to '&lt'. Return the escaped value.
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                function escapeXML($elementValue){

                        $escapedValue = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $elementValue);
                        $escapedValue = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $escapedValue);

                        return $escapedValue;

                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a conflict with Magebright_DeferJS extension. It "cuts" the .js scriptis in some way, so the checkout can not work. If this extension is disabled, everything works properly